# Spark BusyIndicator not working

Tags: apache-flex, busyindicator

I have a busy function taking several of seconds to be executed. At the top of the function I set my busy indicator to be visible and at the bottom I set it to be invisible. But the display does not change while the function is executed and the busy indicator does not appear. here is the code structure

`public function busyFunction():void{
busyIndicator.visible = true;
doStuff .. // takes several seconds
busyIndicator.visible = false;
}`

i just want the first line (`busyIndicator.visible = true`) to be executed while the `doStuff` is on progress.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because Flex doesn't redraw the screen while your method is executing. So you make the busy indicator visible, do stuff, and hide the indicator. But no update to the screen will have occurred yet, so the indicator never shows.

The Flex "elastic racetrack" paradigm basically says that your app consists of two cycles, one where your logic is executed, and another where the screen is updated. So you need to set the busy indicator to visible, and then make it go away after at least one update cycle later.

To make this sort of thing work, you need to execute `doStuff()` asynchronously. Some code that does this might look like this:

```
private function startDoingStuff():void
{
    busyIndicator.visible = true;
    // dispatch "doStuff" event
    dispatchEvent(new Event("doStuff"));
    return; // returning here is important don't do stuff here
}

private function onDoStuff(e:Event):void
{
    // do stuff;
    busyIndicator.visible = false;
}
```

Another idea is to use Flex's `callLater()` method to execute your `doStuff()` method. This should guarantee that `doStuff()` is executed on the next cycle:

```
private function startDoingStuff():void
{
    busyIndicator.visible = true;
    callLater(onDoStuff);
}

private function onDoStuff():void
{
    // do stuff
    busyIndicator.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sunil, thank you first, but i am having the same situation after implementing the callLater method. the busy indicator is hidden by the function. And how can i pass parameters in the first option u provided? my doStuff(j:int) takes parameter like this ..

Comment: @user2415906 to pass parameters with the first option, you have to create your own class that extends `Event`, and add such a property to the event. But this is not likely to work, if the `callLater()` approach didn't work.

Comment: @user2415906 perhaps as a trouble shooting step, you could make sure the busy indicator is working by never making it invisible and letting it remain on screen. Also, you might try using `callLater()` twice. Use `callLater()` at the end of `doStuff()` as well, to call another function that simply hides the busy indicator... a hack indeed, good luck!